# unable to display Google Chart with json table

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, hook

I'm fairly new to the coding world so please have mercy regarding my obsolete SQL connection although the wpdp class does exist. I am aware of this, but for some reasons, it doesn't work and that's another topic...

I try to write my own plugin to connect to my sql database, query some stuff and then provide a google chart with a jsontable. The code works If I use it in a stand alone .php file. However, as soon as I activate do_action nothing works and my whole page is white.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: mm_gchart
Description: -
Version: 1.0.0
Author: MM
*/

function mm_gct_data() {
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","xx","xx","xx");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
//echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
//echo "Hello";
$sql="SELECT gewicht, wdh FROM testtable";
$query=mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$rows=array();
$table=array();
$table['cols'] = array(
    array('label' => 'Gewicht', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'Wiederholungen', 'type' => 'number')
);
while ($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) 
{
$temp=array();
$temp[]=array('v' => (int) $r['gewicht']);
$temp[]=array('v' => (int) $r['wdh']);
$rows[]=array('c' => $temp);
}
global $jsonTable;
$table['rows'] = $rows;
$jsonTable = json_encode($table);
}

add_action('init', 'mm_gct_data'); 
//do_action( 'init','mm_gct_data' );
?>
```

I would be super happy, if somebody could work some black magic on my code and then provide a simple description.

Thanks in advance!

Edit after replies:

Thank you very much for your fast reply! If the do_action() command was not the reason for my blank page, then what is?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
    google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']}); 
    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart); 
    function drawChart() {
     // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$jsonTable?>);
      var options = {
        title: 'Testing',
        width: 600,
        height: 400
      };
      // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <div id="chart_div"></div>

    <p>Everything went well..</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Update code to `<div id="chart_div"></div><?="If you see this line, then short_open_tag has been enabled. If not, you need to enable it"?>` to test.

Answer (score 0):

You should not make a call to `do_action()` as you have it in your code. This action hook is built into WordPress and will be called automatically as part of its running. The WordPress site has a list of the [Actions Run During a Typical Request](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Actions_Run_During_a_Typical_Request) on their site.

It is appropriate to make a call to [`do_action()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_action) when you want to implement a custom action hook for other developers to plug in to. Calls to `add_action()` can be made to add events to your hook.

Comment: To add to @doublesharp's answer, here is a list of hooks you can run `add_action()` for. [Plugin API Hooks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Hooks_2.0.x).